# Fill screen with 2D cubes dynamically accordingly Screen.width

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to use a for loop to instantiate cube as much fit on the screen. So i checked how wide the screen is and is checked how wide my cube was. Divided it by each other and it didnt work.

So what i think i did wrong is that Screen.width is in pixels and renderer.bounds.size.x is in world size.

How do i fix this? I didnt figure it out on the internet..

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public static bool spawn;
    float times;
    int screenWidth;
    float objectSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        spawn = true;
        screenWidth = Screen.width;
        objectSize = GameObject.Find("vork").GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
        times = screenWidth / objectSize;


    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(spawn == true)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < times;i++) {
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3(i * 2, i *2, 0);
                Instantiate(cubePrefab, pos, transform.rotation);
            }
            spawn = false;
        }
    }

}
```

[2D game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edjed.png)

Comment: Check `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`

Comment: May i ask to elaborate? Cause https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html 
says that it converts a position to screenspace. I have width im dealing with

Comment: width and position are in the same units, also default box has size 1

Comment: So i can check where a object is in the screen. But i don't know it's screensize. Only then i can check how many how of my object fit in the screen.

Comment: Forget the screen size, select both the cube and the camera, then in the scene window switch to the top-down view, you will see a trapezoid which represents the camera, when an edge of the cube across the trapezoid, it covers the screen. So this is a simple mathmatic calculation.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6b9505f6d0a0de0d983068d6fde83217

So topdownview. what do you mean with "when an edge of the cube across the trapezoid, it covers the screen"? 

It's 2D..

Comment: Sure, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate pixel width. In order to calculate screen position from world position use Camera.WorldToScreenPoint. This is how a function could look like:

```
public static float GetPixelWidth(GameObject gO)
{
    Bounds bounds = gO.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;
    Vector3 boundsPos1 = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(gO.transform.position.x + bounds.extents.x, gO.transform.position.y, gO.transform.position.y));
    Vector3 boundsPos2 = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(gO.transform.position.x - bounds.extents.x, gO.transform.position.y, gO.transform.position.y));
    return Vector3.Distance(boundsPos1, boundsPos2);
}
```

And this is how to use the function in your code:

```
    // Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    spawn = true;
    screenWidth = Camera.main.pixelWidth;
    objectSize = GetPixelWidth(GameObject.Find("vork"));
    times = screenWidth / objectSize;
}
```

I have tested and it works with orthographic camera

Comment: Dude, it works like a charm. I know also why i didn't get it. I thought there had to be a function that turned the width of an object to pixels. 

You simple check the 2 sides of the object and calculate the size yourself. Thank you very much! 

Gif for working proof: https://gyazo.com/1f030f1712f29cf7f469745731d9b65a

Comment: I am glad it helped ;) The simpler the solution the better.